# reactable custom cell rendering with HTML content does not render HTML

Tags: html, r, reactable

I am using a custom cell rendering function for one column with `reactable` that combines both columns of a dataframe, one of which is already HTML (`<p>something</p>`). I cannot get the HTML rendering to work.

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)

data <- data.frame(
  when = Sys.time(),
  what = "<p>this is the message</p>"
)

reactable(data,
          columns = list(
            when = colDef(show = FALSE),
            what = colDef(
              html = TRUE,
              cell = function(value, index, name){
                
                tagList(
                  tags$span(" Sent on: ", tags$i(data$when[index])),
                  tags$br(),
                  htmltools::HTML(data$what[index])
                )
                
              }
            )
          )
)
```

The message part will show as `<p>this is the message</p>` in the table.

Perhaps a custom JS rendering function is a solution but the actual application needs a custom R function (with lots of other stuff).

I have tried all combinations of `html` argument to `colDef` and also the `HTML()` around the message.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Raw HTML via `htmltools::HTML` is not supported at the moment in `{reactable}`](https://github.com/glin/reactable/issues/95#issuecomment-727260109).

So as per the suggestion by @Greg Lin (author of `reactable`), we can convert the whole `tagList` into raw HTML string using `as.character` and then render it as raw HTML using `html=TRUE`.

```
library(reactable)
library(htmltools)

data <- data.frame(
  when = Sys.time(),
  what = "<p>this is the message</p>"
)

reactable(data,
          columns = list(
            when = colDef(show = FALSE),
            what = colDef(
              html = TRUE,
              cell = function(value, index, name) {
                tag_list <- tagList (
                  tags$span(" Sent on: ", tags$i(data$when[index])),
                  tags$br(),
                  HTML(data$what[index])
                )
                as.character(tag_list)
              }
            )
))
```

---

[image: raw HTML in reactable cell]

---